# What is the correct PHP configuration to connect to MS SQL 2000/2005?

Tags: php, sql-server, windows, iis-6

I have a number of servers running [PHP 5.2.6 (non-thread-safe build)](http://museum.php.net/php5/php-5.2.6-nts-Win32.zip) on Windows 2003/IIS6 utilising FastCGI.

I'm having some issues connecting to MS SQL 2000/2005 (MySQL connectivity is working fine, ASP/ASP.NET scripts can connect to MS SQL successfully as well). [One solution](http://www.userscape.com/helpdesk/index.php?pg=kb.page&id=13) suggests copying the SQL Client Tools `ntwdblib.dll` file to the PHP extensions folder or installing all of the SQL Client Tools on the web server (which I'm reluctant to do).

Another solution suggested is to use the [Microsoft SQL Server 2005 Driver for PHP](http://blogs.msdn.com/sqlphp/archive/2008/07/28/microsoft-sql-server-2005-driver-for-php-v1-0-has-released.aspx). This looks fine for writing greenfield apps but for applications such as phpBBS or WordPress this doesn't appear to work.

For example, the following script:

```
<?php 
$host = "mssqlhost"; 
$user = "phpbb2"; 
$password = "phpbb2"; 

$connect_sql_server = mssql_connect($host, $user, $password); 
?>
```

Fails with:

> PHP Warning: mssql_connect()
>   [function.mssql-connect]: Unable to
>   connect to server: mssqlhost in
>   E:\AppsDev.NET_UK_Minds\phpSqlNC\www\test.php
>   on line 6

The goal is to allow PHP scripts to connect to both SQL 2000 and SQL 2005 which are running on different servers. I should also add that upgrading to a later version of PHP isn't an option at this time.

What is the correct way to configure PHP on Windows 2003/IIS6 to connect to SQL 2000/2005?

Comment: The fact that you get that message seems like it's working. Are you sure the host is OK (your typing MYSql host and using MSSql_connect)? Can you connect to the server with a client (to test connectivity).

Comment: Connectivity is fine and verified using SQL management studio. This seems to be a known issue with PHP + MS SQL but there seems to be so many different stories about how to solve.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After trying various 'solutions' it turns out that the problem was solved simply by replacing the `ntwdblib.dll` file in the PHP executables folder.

There is no need to install any of: *SQL Native Client*, *SQL Client Tools* or *Microsoft SQL Server 2005 Driver for PHP*, as many dead ends have suggested.

All that needs done is to ensure that `ntwdblib.dll` version 2000.80.2039.0 is dropped into the `c:\php` folder (or wherever you've installed/uncompressed PHP to) and then reset IIS. The PHP docs [suggest](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mssql.requirements.php) copying `ntwdblib.dll` to %SYSTEMROOT%\System32 which doesn't work and they also suggest that this will only support named pipes which is also wrong.

I haven't tried to see if a later version of `ntwdblib.dll` works or not, but 2000.80.2039.0 works for me.

Comment: The PHP docs would suggest system32 because this can be the default PHP location.

Do you know of the official site to get the ntwdblib.dll from? I googled and found one but would like to know where to get the latest version.

I had enabled MSSQL.dll in php.ini but when going to cmd and doing php -m to list all modules, an error box appeared saying I was missing ntwdblib.dll which led me here :D

Comment: We have lots SQL 2000 SP4 on site so I basically grabbed it from one of the servers and copied to the web server.

Comment: Version 2000.80.194.0 worked for me too (PHP 5.2, SQL Server 2008 R2 Express)

Answer (score 2):

Not really an answer, but more helpful information...

The version of ntwdblib.dll (2000.2.8.0) that comes with latest php 5.2.X works great with Apache and MSSQL (2008). I have a copy of the DLL from the 2000.80.X.X versions and it is newer than what comes with PHP. I don't know if this makes it better.

The "mssql_" functions are not included in the [official msft php mssql](http://blogs.msdn.com/sqlphp/) driver. They have changed them to a different naming convention. ("sqlsrv_") That link you posted is version 1.0 but they are already on version 1.1. The "mssql_" functions require that the ntwdblib.dll be present.

Comment: I got my issues resolved and have been following developments regarding MS SQL and the official drivers. Thanks for the info.

Comment: No problem. Just FYI, it appears that all the "mssql_" functions have been dropped in 5.3 because this file is not included currently.

Answer (score -1):

### Apache 2.2.14 /PHP 5.2.12/MS-SQL 2008 integration

- Download Apache 2.2.14 for Windows Installer package 2008 32 bit
  httpd DOT apache DOT org/download.cgi --> apache_2.2.14-win32-x86-no_ssl
- follow the defaults when installing Apache
- stop Apache 2.2 service
- Download PHP 5.2.12 Windows Zip package for Windows 2008 32 bit;
  (VC6 Thread Safe version needed for PHP used as an Apache module).

windows DOT php DOT net/download/  --> php-5.2.12-Win32-VC6-x86.zip
- Extract the archive to C:\PHP 
- Verify the installation:  C:\PHP>php -v
- set the Environment Variable PHPRC=C:\PHP
- Rename 'C:\PHP\php.ini-recommended' to 'C:\PHP\php.ini'
- Edit C:\PHP\php,ini file:

```
modify:     extension_dir = "C:\PHP\ext"
uncomment:  extension=php_mssql.dll
```

- Add the lines below to "C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\conf\httpd.conf"

  ```
  PHPIniDir "C:/PHP/"
  LoadModule php5_module "C:/PHP/php5apache2_2.dll"
  AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php
  ```
- Add the lines below to "C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\conf\mime.types"

  ```
  application/x-httpd-php php
  application/x-httpd-php-source  phps
  ```
- Ensure that phpinfo.php file with the content:  is in the folder
  C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\htdocs
- Start Apache 2.2 service
- Verification of Apache/PHP integration: http://localhost/phpinfo.php --> 'PHP Version 5.2.12' info shows up
- Verification whether mssql' module is loaded: c:\php\php -m

All works like a charm ... no additional steps needed.