# how to connect and configure php with sqlserver

Tags: php, sql-server

I want to connect php with sql server
and also configure php for using sql server.

Can anyone tell me step by step starting with configure php to connecting php with sql server
plz help me?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/book.mssql.php

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc793139%28v=sql.90%29.aspx

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the correct PHP configuration to connect to MS SQL 2000/2005?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/747477/what-is-the-correct-php-configuration-to-connect-to-ms-sql-2000-2005)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please consult the PHP manual and review the material on [Mssql](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.mssql.php).  This is a built-in extension that you should have available, verify by reviewing the results from `<?php phpinfo(); ?>`.  If its not available then it may be enabled by adding `extension=php_mssql.dll` to php.ini. If you need more help than that then refer to the manual.

You would begin with a simple [mssql_connect](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mssql-connect.php) to connect to a MSSQL server from PHP.  The rest is in the docs...

You can also review [SQL Server Driver for PHP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/ff657782.aspx) if it turns out that you can't use the Mssql extension.

Comment: in my php.ini file i add extension=php_mssql.dll and i put dll file in ext folder.when i restart its gives me error like msssql:unable to initialize module.

Answer (score -1):

It's simply just two lines!

This is an example for a MySQL server:

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost", "username", "password") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("your_db_name") or die(mysql_error());
?>
```

Then you can start doing queries towards your SQL server.

Comment: I completely misunderstood your question. I do not have the knowledge to answer about Microsoft SQL Server. (encapsulated for better understanding..)

Comment: plz read question.i want to connect mssql.